# qgis2threejs 3d model export problems

Tags: export, qgis2threejs

I have kind of spikes around my 3D model and can't seem to get a clean contour. Anyone knows what I need to change to get?

[image]

Comment: If you thy to export a slightly smaller extend of your 3D scene, the problem persists? Like clipping the area to be exported (kind of a negative buffer)? Best way to help you would be if you could provide your data for testing, if that's possible.

Answer (score 1):

The cause could be several things. Without more info, I'd suggest:

- [in the standard planimetric QGIS window] digitise a polygon that falls within the footprint of the DEM (can be a temporary layer)
- [in the table-of-contents of the qgis2threejs preview window] right-click on the DEM, and click "Clip DEM with polygon layer" in the "Geometry" sub-pane of the Properties box, select polygon layer you digitised

note: this just makes your issue invisible and doesn't necessarily address the problem